# Indexing a vector function, E(s)=(E_1(s),E_2(s),E_3(s)), in Matlab without evaluating the function

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

This is simple, but for some reason I can't find the solution anywhere on the Internet. I have a vector function in Matlab:

```
E(s) = [E_1(s),E_2(s),E_3(s)]
```

I want to be able to index it, so normally in Matlab you would use `E(1)`, for the first element. However this just evaluates the vector at `s` equals `2`. `E(s)(1)` also gives an error.

Here's [my code](http://pastebin.com/vCuxkchN) for reference.

Comment: You're vector function is not included in your code, so I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Could you provide the code that  is giving you the error?

Comment: Just answered over at [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495519/indexing-a-vector-function-es-e-1s-e-2s-e-3s-in-matlab-without-eva) and then found that you double posted here. I'll repeat my answer for the benefit of this audience, but double posting should be avoided. You might even consider taking down the Math.SE one as this is not really a question about mathematics.

Comment: @horchler: You are probably right, I thought it was acceptable due to the existance of the MATLAB tag, however it makes more sense for it to be here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a symbolic function that returns a vector. Type `whos` and you'll see that the class of `E` is `symfun`. Unfortunately, I don't think that you can directly index into a symbolic function. However, you can convert it into a symbolic expression (class `sym`) simply by setting it equal to a new variable and passing in your symbolic variable `s`

```
Es = E(s);
```

Now you should be able to evaluate `Es(1)`, `Es(2)`, and `Es(3)` as you wanted.

Comment: Many thanks for this. So this takes the 1x1 symfun -> 3x1 sym. I can now extract the elements are you pointed out, however how do I then recover the functionality of the Es(1) object?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Are you asking how you can plug in values for `s` and the other symbolic variables? If so, you can just use [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html). Or you can turn each element of the `Es` vector back into a symbolic function, e.g., `Es2(s) = symfun(Es(2),s)`. Then you can do `Es2(3)` to evaluate the second element at `s` equal to 3. Play around, many options are possible and you may be able to figure out how to re-vectorize it if that's what you want.

Comment: p.s. your research looks so exciting! I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your only hope is to use the command "eval."  Type "help eval" and see if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it and sadly no luck, its a <1x1 symfun> object, an output from the 'eig' function, that creates a <3x1 sym> array. The <1x1 symfun> object is identical except for some reason I can access it's elements!